# python - change element while in for loop

Tags: python, sorting

Let's say we have three lists:

```
listA = [5,6,2]
listB = [7,1]
listC = [5,3,6]
```

I would like to sort those lists in one `for` loop, so do something like:

```
for thisList in [listA, listB, listC]:  # edited, was 'list' here
    thisList = thisList.sort()
```

where `thisList` would be `listA`, then `listB`, then `listC`, so at the end my lists would be like this:

```
listA = [2,5,6]
listB = [1,7]
listC = [3,5,6]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Note - this is just an example, the problem I'm dealing with is kinda harder, but I wanted to make a simple example of what I need.

--edit--

What if I would like to make some custom sorting here?
I know that, for example, I can make custom sorting this way:
    myList = sorted(myList, key= lambda val: val/2)

but I'm using `sorted`, not `sort` here.

Can I use custom sorting in `sort`?

Asking cause given answers (thx btw ;) ) are using `sort`...

Comment: [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) sorts a list in-place and returns `None`, so `thisList = thisList.sort()` will first sort the old list in-place, then forget it and reassign `thisList` to `None`, which doesn't seem very useful. What exactly did you _want_ it to do?

Comment: `for sublist in list_of_lists: sublist.sort()`

Comment: Isn't your example working like you want?

Comment: @MykhayloKopytonenko: No, because `thisList` is not the loop variable that gets `listA`, then `listB`, then `listC`; it's presumably something he used earlier in the module or interactive session that has nothing to do with the lists he's looping over…

Comment: I added an answer with sorted, you have to asign the value, its the only difference

Comment: You've edited your question into a completely different question; don't do that. Plus, it's one that you can answer for yourself with a second's glance at the online help for [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) and [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted): they both take `key` arguments that do the same thing.

Comment: Also, what's the point of `key=lambda val: val/2` supposed to be? The only way that will be different than no key at all is that is if you've got two floats that differ by one bit (e.g., the smallest subnormal positive and 0) they may be treated as if they're equal.

Comment: @abarnert That `val/2` was just an example ;) Should proably put something more like `sin(val)`. In my case in will be last 16 digits of account numbers, but I didn't want to complicate my example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close. What you want is:

```
for thisList in [listA, listB, listC]:
    thisList.sort()
```

The first problem in your code is that you were using `list` as the loop variable, but `thisList` inside the loop. Those aren't the same. So, whatever you had previously assigned to `thisList` earlier in the module or interactive session, you were just sorting that over and over again, without affecting `listA`, `listB`, and `listC`.

The second problem is that the [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method sorts the list in-place and returns `None`, so you don't want to do anything with that return value. It's *harmless* to overwrite the `thisList` variable with `None`, but it's certainly confusing to the reader, so don't do it.

---

Since you've edited the question into something different:

> What if I would like to make some custom sorting here? I know that, for example, I can make custom sorting this way: myList = sorted(myList, key= lambda val: val/2) … Can I use custom sorting in sort?

Look at the docs for [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort). Both of them take a `key` argument, and both document it the same way. If you can't guess from that whether they actually work the same way, it would take a couple seconds to test it for yourself:

```
>>> lst = [2, 11]
>>> sorted(lst, key=str)
[11, 2]
>>> lst.sort(key=str)
>>> lst
[11, 2]
```

Comment: @Kasra: Not if you want to actually affect what's in the `listA`, `listB`, and `listC` variables, which is what it seems like he wants to do.

Comment: I edited my question a little, pls check it I You can :)

Answer (score 5):

Don't name your variables with a number, or a letter. Put all lists in another list. Then you can operate on theses objects in for-loops:

```
lists = [listA, listB, listC]

for lst in lists:
    lst.sort()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for l in [list1, list2, list3]:
    l.sort()
```

On a side note, do not use the reserved word `list` when looping through them

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listA = [5,6,2]

listB = [7,1]

listC = [5,3,6]

lists = [listA, listB, listC]

for indx, list in enumerate(lists):
    lists[indx] = sorted(list)



In [52]: lists
Out[52]: [[2, 5, 6], [1, 7], [3, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: No; this just repeatedly reassigns the `list` variable without affecting the actual `listA`, `listB`, and `listC` lists.

Comment: Yeah its strange, for some reason it worked for me the first time, I rushed the answer